# Where to deploy a (database) file for read/write access for all users?

Tags: wpf, sqlite, deployment, directory, appdata

I have a WPF application targeting .Net 4.0 and am using SQLite with
the ADO.NET provider and Entity Framework.

I do need to have read write access to the database file after
deployment. My work colleagues and I have been searching, and in
debate, for the best most feasible location to deploy the database
file. I have been thinking the *appdata* Roaming directory is the best
fit, however, my colleague has stated that the *appdata* directory is
separate per Windows user. We need to figure a directory that will
allow the file to be deployed once per computer and allow all users to
access the file.

Any suggestions on the most logical directory to deploy the database file to will be greatly appreciated.